# Can't create new file or folder in Remix while using Brave

Tags: remix

Anyone know if there's a setting in Brave that might be preventing me from adding a file or folder to Remix?  I'm also wondering if there's a limit in Remix that might be preventing me from adding files/folders after a certain number of either have already been added?

Answer (score 0):

I've it open in the next tab, and it is working just fine.

In the past some updates have broken the workspace, so you can try removing it and creating a new one. Make sure to make a backup of your workspace (you can do it in remix welcome page).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my brave so i think the issue can be resolved with

- Removing the cache of remix
- Removing the storage files that gets saved on remix
- Removing the cookies
- Updating your brave browser

Let me know if these methods have worked you :>